# lag.plot in R as in Stata

Tags: r, stata

I want to plot a scatter of the residual and its first-order lag, i.e., plotting $(e_{t-1},e_{t})$, as well as adding the least square line in **Stata**.  My little demo is from `Example 2.3 The U.S. Gasoline Market` in *Econometric Analysis (7e, William H. Greene)* that shows

```
use http://web.pdx.edu/~crkl/ec570/data/gasoline
describe
summarize
generate g=ln(gasexp/pop)  
generate y=ln(income/pop)  
generate pg=ln(gasp)       
generate pnew=ln(pnc)      
generate pused=ln(puc) 
tsset year     
regress g y pg pnew pused
predict e, residual
twoway scatter e l.e || lfit e l.e
```

where `l.e` means the (first order) lag operator on the residual `e`, and the related figure is given by

[image]

I want to reproduce the figure using **R** and I try

```r
library(foreign)
gasoline = read.dta('http://web.pdx.edu/~crkl/ec570/data/gasoline.dta')
attach(gasoline)
gasoline$g=log(gasexp/pop)
gasoline$y=log(income/pop)
gasoline$pg=log(gasp)     
gasoline$pnew=log(pnc)    
gasoline$pused=log(puc)   
str(gasoline)
head(gasoline)

gasoline1 = ts(gasoline, start=1953, frequency=1)
library(dynlm) #help(package="dynlm")
f = dynlm(g ~ y + pg + pnew + pused, data=gasoline1)
summary(f)
e = resid(f)
plot(e~lag(e,-1), xlab="Residuals, L", ylab="Residuals", type='p')
abline(lm(e~lag(e,-1)), col='red')
```

and the figure shows

[image]

It seems that the argument `type='p'` doesn't work!

I search the internet and find `lag.plot` to do

```r
lag.plot(e, lag=-1)
```

and it gives

[image]

Still, it is not satisfactory! How can I remedy this?

Comment: It's unclear how throwing away the ordering of the association between residuals and prior residual can be a step forward. The plot methods for the dynlm objects allows you to look at the ordering in two different ways while the regression plot that Stata offers is relatively uninformative with respect to the nature of the implied nonlinearity of the departure from the regression assumptions.

Comment: Yes, you're  right! I will try it according to your clue. @IRTFM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At its most basic, you can just do a scatterplot of `lag(e)` versus `e` with a regression line between the two variables:

```r
plot(lag(e), e)
abline(lm(e ~ lag(e)))
```

[image]

If you want something more sophisticated, the following ggplot code nicely replicates the Stata output:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mapping = aes(lag(e), e)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, col = '#1a476f', aes(shape = 'Residuals')) +
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm', se = FALSE, fullrange = FALSE, col = '#8a2b31',
              aes(linewidth = 'Fitted values')) +
  ylim(c(-0.3, 0.1)) +
  xlim(c(-0.3, 0.1)) +
  scale_shape(name = NULL) +
  scale_linewidth_manual(name = NULL, values = 0.5) +
  labs(y = NULL, x = 'Residuals, L') +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom',
        plot.background = element_rect(color = NA, fill = '#eaf2f3'),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(linewidth = 0.1, color = 'gray'),
        legend.spacing.x = unit(0, 'mm'),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = 'white',
                                             color = 'black', linewidth = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Very impressive! Especially your sophisticated part! Appreciated! @Allan-Cameron